# Variance of sample mean

Tags: probability, statistics

Reading a paper by this [link](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/BrownClasses/162/Handouts/StatsTests04.pdf) I found the next expression (page 4):

$\begin{align}
Var(Y) = Var(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i) = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N Var(X_i) = \frac{1}{N^2} N Var(X) = \frac{Var(X)}{N} 
\end{align}$

that is very clear for me.
But trying to get the same result in a more straight way I'm getting the next result:

$\begin{align}
Var(Y) & = Var(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i) \\
& = E((\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i)^2) - E(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{N^2}E(\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N X_i X_j) - \frac{1}{N^2} E(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{N^2}(\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N E(X_i X_j) - (\sum_{i=1}^N E(X_i))^2) \\
& = \frac{1}{N^2}(N^2 E(X^2) - N^2 E(X)^2) \\
& = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 \\
& = Var(X)
\end{align}$

(where $X_i$ is a random variable drawn from some distribution)
that contravers to first expression.

I took a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113644/variance-of-sample-mean) but there is no any deep answer related to this.

Could somebody to help me to understand what is wrong?

P.S. It is my first question on this resource, please not be very strict to how my question has been formed but provide some advices instead, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that in general $E(X_i X_j) \neq E(X^2)$. Instead, the [formula of expected value of a product](https://dlsun.github.io/probability/ev-product.html) tells us that for **independent** random variables $A$, $B$ it holds that
$E(AB) = E(A)E(B)$.

As defined in the linked paper, $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are **independent**
identically distributed random variables. That means that for $i \neq j$
it holds that $E(X_i X_j) = E(X_i)E(X_j) = {(E(X))}^2$. However, for $i = j$
the variables $X_i = X_j$ are not independent, but instead the expression
simplifies as $E(X_i X_j) = E(X_i X_i) = E(X^2)$.

When this mistake is fixed, by completing the derivation we can get the correct result:

$\begin{align*}
Var(Y) &= \frac{1}{N^2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N E(X_i X_j) - (\sum_{i=1}^N E(X_i))^2\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{N^2} \left(\sum_{i\neq j}^N E(X_i X_j) + \sum_{i=1}^N E(X_i X_i)- (\sum_{i=1}^N E(X_i))^2\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{N^2} \left(\sum_{i\neq j}^N {(E(X))}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N E(X^2)- (\sum_{i=1}^N E(X))^2\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{N^2} \left((\color{green}{N^2} - N)\color{green}{{(E(X))}^2} + N E(X^2) \color{green}{- N^2 {(E(X))}^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{N^2} \left( NE(X^2) - N {(E(X))}^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{E(X^2) - {(E(X))}^2}{N} \\
&= \frac{Var(X)}{N}. \\
\end{align*}$