# Proof that MLE of variance is biased

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation

Was reading Wikipedia's proof that the maximum likelihood estimator of variance is biased. Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Examples).

I follow the proof until the very last step. We have, $$\sigma^2-E[(\bar{X}-\mu)^2].$$ Noting that $\bar{X}$ is sample mean we rewrite this as, $$\sigma^2-E\bigg[\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i+\frac{1}{n}\mu\bigg)^2\bigg],$$ but I don't see how it follows that this is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n}\sigma^2$.

Comment: I think you have an error when you substituted in the formula for the sample mean.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979299/variance-of-sample-mean-problems-with-proof

Comment: And [_here_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113644/variance-of-sample-mean/2113753#2113753).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for some r.v. $X$ 
$$
\operatorname{var}(X) = \mathbb{E}( X - \mathbb{E}[X] ) ^ 2,
$$
and $\mathbb{E}\bar{X}_n = \mu$, hence
$$
\mathbb{E}( \bar{X}_n - \mu ) ^ 2 = \operatorname{var}(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} .
$$